# How to get local timezone in ejs?

Tags: node.js, timezone, ejs, timezone-offset

I am using `ejs template` and my server have `UTC time` format. I need to convert my timezone into local timezone on user side.

When i use this `<% new Date() %>`this date show server time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send your `timezoneoffset` client side to server and after that when you render your pagefrom server to client using `ejs` that time send one more parameter `timezoneoffset` and using this you can convert your time into local time. `timeZoneOffset` and `serverDate` is come from server and `TIMEOFFSET` is local variable. `serverDate` is in `UTC` format.

```
<% var TIMEOFFSET = timeZoneOffset;
    TIMEOFFSET = TIMEOFFSET*(-1);
    var dateForShow = serverDate;
    dateForShow.setMinutes(dateForShow.getMinutes() + TIMEOFFSET); %>
```

Comment: What if we want to send a template to another client residing at a different timezone?